# Weblogic migratable JMS consumer doesn't follow the service to the new managed server if the old server remains running

Tags: migration, jms, weblogic

I have a JMS service targeted at a migratable target (using an Auto-Migrate Exactly-Once policy) in a cluster which consists of 2 managed servers, at any point of time the service is hosted at one of them and the consumer (which is targeted at the cluster) is supposed to receive messages seamlessly no matter where the service is hosted.

When I manually switch the host of the migratable target (clicking migrate), without turning the hosting managed server off, the consumer fails to receive messages sent to the queues, unless I turn off the previous hosting managed server forcing the consumer to the new host.

I can rule out sender problems, I can see the messages in the queue right after them being sent.

I'll be grateful if anyone can advice on how to configure either the consumer or the migratable service to work seamlessly when migration happens.

Comment: Have you tried to "crash" one of your servers to see if it migrates and works? I wonder if it has to do with forcing the migration via the console

Comment: Like I said, when switching off a managed server that hosted the target, it forces the target to migrate to the 2nd managed server and works perfect. The problem is when I keep the managed server running but initiate the migration manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think that may just be a misunderstanding of how migration works. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jms_servers/ConfigureMigratableTargetsForJMSServers.html) state Auto-Migrate Exactly-Once:

> indicates that if at least one Managed Server in the candidate list
>   is running, then the JMS service will be active somewhere in the
>   cluster if servers should fail or are shut down (either gracefully or
>   forcibly). For example, a migratable target hosting a path service
>   should use this option so if its hosting server fails or is shut down,
>   the path service will automatically migrate to another server and so
>   will always be active in the cluster. Note that this value can lead to
>   target grouping. For example, if you have five exactly-once migratable
>   targets and only one server member is started, then all five
>   migratable targets will be activated on that server member.

The docs also state:

> Manual Service Migration—the manual migration of pinned JTA and
>   JMS-related services (for example, JMS server, SAF agent, path
>   service, and custom store) after the host server instance fails

Your server/service has neither failed or shut down, you are forcing it to migrate with a healthy host still running, so it has not met the criteria for migration.

See more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13709/service_migration.htm#CLUST347) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience that sounds reminiscent of what you're looking at. There was some WLS-specific capability around recognizing reconfiguration in JMS destinations as part of their clustered server design.

In one case I had to call a WLS-specific method: weblogic.jms.extensions.WLSession.setExceptionListener(). This was on their implementation of the JMS Session interface. This is analogous to the standard JMS Connection.setExceptionListener().

With this WLS-specific capability, the WLSession.setExceptionListener() callback would occur at a point where the consuming client should tear down and re-establish the connection / session / consumer in reaction to a reconfiguration (migration) that had happened.